# Energy stored in a coaxial cable before reaching breakout field

Tags: electromagnetism, energy

Yesterday I had a (multiple choice) exam and the following was one of the questions.

We have a coaxial cable (basically two coaxial conducting cylinders) with the inner radius of $a$ (variable) and outer radius of $b$ (constant) filled with vacuum. Find the radius $a$ so that the maximum energy is stored in the cable before it reaches the breakout field $E_b$.

The thing is that, non of the answer choices included the $E_b$ parameter in them. So I thought the question might be wrong. Any answer I can think of must include $E_b$. Am I missing something or the question is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since this question seems to be of the "homework and exercises" variety, I will, in keeping with the policy on this site, initially give just a pointer to the solution, rather than a fully worked example.  See how far you get with this.

Regardless of what the break**down** (not break**out**) voltage is, there is an optimal solution for radius to maximize energy stored. The correct approach should do the following two things:

1) compute the energy stored at a given voltage, and for a given value of $a$ (assuming fixed value of outer conductor radius $b$). Recall that $E = \frac12 C V^2$ and for a cylindrical capacitor, $C \propto \frac{1}{\log{(b/a)}}$

2) compute the electric field at the surface of the inner conductor (the largest field strength) at a given voltage V

Now you use the formula you found in (2) and substitute it into (1) - you end up with the energy as a function of breakdown voltage and radius. Find the maximum in that expression. While the value of the energy will be a function of the breakdown field, the radius is not.

Update your question with the work if this doesn't solve it (or even if it does...)